# virtual method not seen in implementation

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

i am currently working on a C++ project where i have an abstract interface that is implemented later on. The interface also has a implemented method which my implementation doesn't override.
My problem is that when using my implementation, the compiler(MSVC) doesn't see the interface method. What causes this, and how can i resolve it?

Here comes the code.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string;

class A
{
    public:
    string name;
};

class interface
{ 
public:
    virtual int num_foo() = 0;
    virtual A* foo(int) = 0;
    virtual A* foo(string &name){
        for ( int i(0); i < num_foo(); i++)
            if ( foo(i)->name == name )
                return foo(i);
        return 0;
    }
};

class implementation : public interface
{
public:
    virtual int num_foo() { return m_foos.size(); }
    virtual A* foo(int i) { 
        //check range 
        return &m_foos[i];
    }
    std::vector<A> m_foos;
};

int main(...)
{
    implementation impl;
    // impl is properly initialized here

    string name( "bar" );
    // here comes my problem, the MSVC compiler doesn't see foo(string &name)
    // and gives an error
    A *a = impl.foo( name );
}
```

Comment: I've pasted your code into my editor to have a look at it, but I gave up on it after I fixed half a dozen errors and it still didn't compile. Is it so hard to provide code that has only the one problem you're asking about? As it is, I cannot see which of the dozens of errors you complain about. Fix your code.

Comment: sorry for the bad code. i have now corrected the errors and now my problem is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name resolution happens before overload resolution. In `impl.foo( name )`, then compiler looks at the `implementation` class and finds only `virtual A& foo(int i)`. It does not look at the base class as it has found a function with the right name.

To correct this use can add a `using interface::foo` declaration to the derived class to pull all of the base versions of `foo` into the derived class for the purposes of overload resolution. Usually, I'd prefer to avoid overloaded functions and I'd probably give the variants of `foo` different function names.

(Other errors are that you don't define `string`, `vector` or `m_ones`; you attempt to use `->` instead of `.` on a reference and you attempt to return 0 in a function returning a reference to an `A`.)

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation as well as two proposed workarounds!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and foreseeing the bad code first provided.

Answer (score 3):

To re-publish base methods (such as foo(string)) in a subclass for overloading, add

```
  using interface::foo;
```

into class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
class implementation : public interface{
    public:
       using interface::foo;
       int num_foo() { return m_foos.size(); }
       A& foo(int i)
       {   //check range
           return m_ones[i];
       }
       vector<A> m_foos;
       vector<A> m_ones;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only an issue because you're accessing the `implementation` interface, which does have a `foo` member, as noted already in the answer by @charles-bailey.

Semantically, what you're trying to call is the `interface` method foo, so you probably should actually call that:

```
int main()
{
    implementation impl;
    string name( "bar" );
    interface& interf = impl;
    A *a = interf.foo( name );
    A *b = interf.foo( 4 );
}
```

This would also allow you to implement the [Non-Virtual Interface idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm), by making `implementation::foo` private. You'd still fail if you try to call `impl.foo` directly, but you'd fail for all argument types, with the same error.

(I know this question is old, but NVI is older...)